# Using Xamarin.Forms with MVVMCross separately

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, mvvmcross

I have some app, made with `MVVMCross` and I want to transfer it to `Xamarin.Forms`. What is more - I want to make this transition bit by bit, e.g. transfering one-two screens from Cross to Forms while keeping the app working.

Is it theoretically possible to do so and maintain correct data flow between app parts? And if the answer is yes, could you show me some directions to start with?

P.S. I know that I can use Cross + Forms together, but the point is to avoid this (if there are other ways exists of course).

Comment: Since xamarin 3.0 you can call xamarin forms from native and embed xamarin forms controls to native.

Comment: But Xamarin.Forms has it's own data binding and MVVM approach. Is it possible to combine it with Cross?

Comment: Mvvm is about notify propertychanged, I didn't try but my best guess is that you can bind xamarin.forms to mvvmcross

Comment: Check out the following links https://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2018/05/08/build-a-xamarin.forms-application.aspx?m=1 https://medium.com/@martijn00/using-mvvmcross-with-xamarin-forms-part-1-eaee5815bb8c

Comment: MVVMCross is meant for Xamarin.Forms. If you mean you are removing MVVMCross Nuget from existing forms project then , I think there will be architectural changes w.r.to ViewModels and methods.